# How to use variable in a declare block?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

```
Declare str varchar2(100);
Begin
str := 'first,last,middle';
select regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) as SeparatedStr
from dual
connect by rownum <= length(str) - length(replace(str, ',', '')) + 1;
end;
```

I'm pretty new to PL/SQL and used to be T-SQL guy. I'm really not sure how to use variable after searching so many articles. Just need help with teaching me how to use the declared variables.

Answer (score 0):

Variable helps to store the result of a select query but it depends on whether the select query is giving a single row or multiple rows as the output.

Replicating your query as below:

```
1.

     DECLARE
        str VARCHAR2(100);
        result VARCHAR2(100);
        BEGIN
        str := 'first,last,middle';
        SELECT str INTO result FROM dual;
        dbms_output.put_line('str: '||result);
        END;
        /

2. As your SELECT query is producing more than one row it can not be assigned into a scalar variable.

DECLARE 
    str VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
    FOR I IN(
    WITH TEST AS
    (SELECT 'first,last,middle' AS str FROM dual)
    SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, ROWNUM) AS separatedstr
    FROM TEST
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str, ',', '')) + 1) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(I.separatedstr);
    END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

Hope this helps.